# Wachsen or anbauen of something else?

Tags: meaning

In English - I am **growing** some seeds. I am sowing them in the soil and caring for them as they grow.

If I am trying to say this in German it seems I should not use *wachsen* - something to do with intransitive in the perfect tense? I should be using *anbauen*.

This seems wrong to me as *anbauen* would suggest I am building or landscaping a garden. If a German person was growing some seeds, how would they say it?

Comment: _"If a German person was growing some seeds, how would they say it?"_ _Aufziehen (von der Saat)_ most probably. Depends on context.

Comment: Note that there is one possibility to use *wachsen* in a transitive construction: *Ich wachse etwas*, which would mean *I'm waxing something*. It is a homonym that has nothing to do with *wachsen* in the meaning of *growing*.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are good sentences in German, both in terms of grammar and pragmatics (established use of terminology in real life).

> Ich säe Radieschen

That's from seeds. It means the act of putting seeds into the ground. It does not refer to the following steps related to the emerging plants.

> Ich ziehe Radieschen.

This usually implies smaller quantities, e.g. as little as only one flower pot of them, or a small garden bed. It can include the entire process, from seed to harvest.

> Ich baue Radieschen an

Full process. This would be a large-scale undertaking then, like a farmer growing 1 hectare of small radish.

> Ich pflanze Radieschen.

This would mean: not from seeds, but from small plants (seedlings) bought e.g. at the local farmers' market, or of course from one's own production.

This terminology is for vegetables and flowers. For trees the terminology would be a bit different.

> Ich setze Fichten.

(Not from seeds but from seedlings.)

> Ich bringe Fichtensetzlinge aus.

(Same, but a larger quantity)

> Ich lege eine Fichtenschonung an.

(This describes the transformation of a plot of land by the above activities.)

> Ich pflanze eine Eiche.

(The oak tree is already larger, may be potted, or taken from a tree nursery.)

> Ich pflanze einen Eichenwald.

(An entire forest of oak trees.)

> Ich ziehe Fichtensetzlinge aus Saatgut / Samen.

(Refers to the individual seedlings.)

> In meiner Baumschule ziehe ich Erlen und Ahörner.

(Can mean "from seeds", or "from seedlings")

Comment: Ich sähe Radieschen ist der Konjunktiv von sehen. Säen ist das korrekte Verb: https://m.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/saehen.shtml

Comment: @infinitezero   - Danke, korrigiert. (Das hatte ich übersäen.)

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation.  It has really helped.

Comment: Bei Bäumen würde ich intuitiv auch den Begriff *pflanzen* verwenden, wenn ich dazu den Samen auf oder in die Erde einbringe. Ansonsten Zustimmung.

Comment: Weil ich gerade stutzig wurde: [AhORNE](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ahorn).

Answer (score 5):

**Anbauen** does have two meanings. One is indeed in construction when you add an additional part to a building. However, anbauen is also used with vegetables, fruits and the like.

> Nächstes Jahr möchte ich in meinem Garten endlich Erdbeeren und Kartoffeln anbauen.

Alternatively you can use anpflanzen.

If you specifically take care of a plant, you can use Panta Rei's suggestion and use "aufziehen".

Answer (score -1):

> I am growing some seeds.

Im Deutschen kann man nicht sagen:

> Ich bin wachsen einige Samen.

Auch nicht mit der allfälligen Wortumstellung:

> Ich bin einige Samen wachsen.

Wir lassen die Samen wachsen:

> I lasse einige Samen wachsen.

oder

> I lasse einige Samen sprießen/keimen.

weil ja nicht der Samen größer und größer wird, sondern sich währenddessen transformiert, ist das später kein Samen mehr ist, aber der Gesamtprozess wäre:

> I lasse einige Pflanzen wachsen.

So weit, wenn man an "wachsen" festhalten will. Ganze Pflanzen oder das Zielprodukt, Gemüse und Früchte, kann man anbauen - Samen baut man aber nicht an. Alternativ auch ziehen:

> Ich ziehe Bananen.

Wahrscheinlich von Ziehen wie in Aufzucht. Anbauen geht schon in den Bereich Landwirtschaft, Gartenbau, deutet auf Planung, Sorgfalt und Verwertung hin aber das ist nicht zwingend.

> Ich pflanze Chilis (an).

beschreibt auch den Beginn des Prozesses, könnte aber auch Setzlinge meinen.

Die reine Aussaat wäre:

> Ich säe Kaffeebohnen.

Comment: Ich würde die negativ- Beispiele weglassen oder das „nicht“ besonders betonen: ich wollte sofort downvoten, weil die ersten beiden Sätze unsinnig sind, erst dann habe ich das „nicht“ gelesen. Ein unaufmerksamer leser wird die ersten beiden Sätze ebenfalls als Lösung ansehen. Ansonsten gute Antwort.